# android studio dependencies apache.commons.logging failure

Tags: android, apache-commons-logging

> dependency commons-logging but failure and throw
>   error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

[image]

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3'
compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.2.RELEASE'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile project(':volley')}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [andle](https://github.com/Jintin/andle) to sync the dependency version you have.

It a little tool I wrote on github: https://github.com/Jintin/andle

After proceed, it show the result in console.

`commons-logging:commons-logging: 1.1.3 -> 99.0-does-not-exist`

If you still want to use it, you can find jar to include instead of using gradle.